# appspot.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.create access

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, github-actions, google-cloud-iam

I have been trying to deploy firebase cloud functions via gcloud. While it was successful from the sandbox environment, when I tried to promote the changes to another environment, I am having this error:

> Error: ***@appspot.gserviceaccount.com does not have
> \ storage.objects.create access to the Google Cloud Storage object. Permission 'storage.objects.create'
> \ denied on resource (or it may not exist).

I already added the Storage Object Admin to the service account in GCP but still facing this same error.
This does not occur during the gcloud deploy itself, but happens on this step:

`/home/runner/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud functions call $schema --region=us-central1 --project=${PROJECT_ID}`

I am using Github workflows to deploy the firebase cloud functions into GCP.

I already added the Storage Object Admin and even the Cloud Functions Admin role to the service account in GCP but still facing this same error.

Comment: Try explicitly granting the role to the service account on the bucket level. Go to the Cloud Storage Browser in the Google Cloud Console, selecting the bucket in question, and adding the **Storage Object Creator** role to the service account. Try revoking the service account's credentials and creating a fresh set of credentials if none of the prior step are successful.